# What is this insect? Found in Peru

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I took the pictures today in Cusco Peru. It is the third insect of its class in a month. I never see it before. I thought that it is a wasp, but I think it's really thin to be a wasp. It's about 4 or 5cm.

I want to know what kind of insect is and if it's dangerous. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very good picture for identification, even I am not the one who can answer here.

Comment: Yeap! Very good quality of photos.

Comment: http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/files/keys-for-nocturnal-workshop-reduced-109651.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So that looks to me like the *Ophioninae* family of wasps, genus *Ophion*. I'll query the list of known species to try to find a more direct match.
[image]

Some evidence exists which notes *Ophion* may [sting when threatened](http://www.uksafari.com/yellow_ophion.htm), but at the same time (and I don't have the reference ready) it's believed that the sting contains no toxin.

As for a positive identification, it's difficult without examining the the features of the wasp extremely close up. Identification keys exist [here](http://www.waspweb.org/Ichneumonoidea/Ichneumonidae/Ophioninae/Keys/index.htm).

Comment: It seems, that I haven't found more direct match, as you promised in your answer. Nor, you haven't answered OP, whether it can be dangerous. An edit would be nice, to clear these things (i.e. remove promise for searching for more details). Thanks!